# Check mark to disable row swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4, checkmark

Sorry Im new to Swift and I wanted to add a check mark functionality to my mock app. How can I add a check mark that would disable the selected row and then enable it when the check mark is deselected? Disable as in the row is visible but not tap-able.

Comment: Check out: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/accessorytype/checkmark. Toggle this on and off

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.
I used a button instead your checkbox.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var checkButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    var enable = true;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func touchButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if enable {
            checkButton.setTitle("Disable", for: .normal)
            textField.isEnabled = false
            enable = false
        } else {
            checkButton.setTitle("Enable", for: .normal)
            textField.isEnabled = true
            enable = true
        }
    }
}
```